# Tracking amount of times an element has been shown on my web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have a online offer brochure (www.itilbud.dk) each time an offer is shown i would like to record it in my database, so I can keep track of views for documentation of rotation. Im using Linq2Sql and ASP.NET MVC 2.

Right now i do the following method each time i load the offers:

```
public List<Offer> LoadAll()
        {
            List<Offer> offers = sdc.Offers.Where(x=>x.Active ==true).OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).ToList();
            IncrementRotation(offers);
            return offers;
        }
private void IncrementRotation(List<Offer> offers)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(IncRotationsAsync));
            thread.Start(offers);
            IncRotationsAsync(offers);
        }

        private void IncRotationsAsync(Object offers)
        {
            List<Offer> updateOffers = (List<Offer>)offers;
            OfferRepository repository = new OfferRepository();
            foreach (Offer o in updateOffers)
            {
                o.Rotations = o.Rotations+1;
                repository.Save(o);
            }
        }
```

That however sometimes fail and is not very good, any idea on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a client side tracking mechanism in your Google Analytics.  It gives you much more information to target/personalise your content and a reporting portal that don't have to build.

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'catalogue', 'view', 'Prod:213');

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understand something, but why do you need so much code to do "UPDATE views SET view_count = view_count+1 WHERE offer_id = ??"